# How to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{4}+3x^{2}+2}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{4}+3x^{2}+2}}dx$$ ? I am trying to evaluate this integral by factorizing $x^{4}+3x^{2}+2$ . Now we can write $x^{4}+3x^{2}+2=(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+2)$ . So, we can write the above integral as $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^{2}+1)(x^{2}+2)}}dx$$ . Now we can write $1$ as $(x^{2}+2)-(x^{2}+1)$ . So, the next step of the integral will become $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+2}{x^{2}+1}}dx$$ $-$ $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}}dx$$ . But after this step, the integral is looking messy. But for integrating $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+2}{x^{2}+1}}dx$$ , I am thinking of substituting $x$ $=$ $tan\theta$ . So, $dx=(sec^{2}\theta) d\theta$ . Now we can write $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+2}{x^{2}+1}}dx$$ $=$ $$\int \sqrt{2+tan^{2}\theta}×sec\theta×d\theta$$ . But now after this process I can't integrate further. Also, I can't integrate $$\int \sqrt{\frac{x^{2}+1}{x^{2}+2}}dx$$ . Please help me out.

Comment: WA gave the result being $-\frac{i\sqrt{x^2+1}\sqrt{x^2+2}F(i\sinh^-1(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}})|2)}{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2+2}}+c$. 

$F(x|m)$ is the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: What is 'WA' ? @Mathxx? I don't know what is that. Is that any calculator?

Comment: Try to search “elliptic integral” in any analytic book for more information. It was explained clearly by Zorich, for example.

Comment: $$-i F\left(\left.i \sinh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right|2\right)$$ is simpler

Comment: WA means wolfram alpha

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much @pie.

Answer (score 1):

$$I:= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^4+3x^2 +1}}dx=\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^2+(x^2+1)}}dx$$
let $x= \tan(t)$
$$I=\int \frac{\sec^2(t)}{\sqrt{\sec^4(t)+\sec^2(t)}}dt=\int \frac{\sec(t)}{\sqrt{\sec^2(t)+1}}dt= \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos^2(t)+1}}dt =\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2-\sin^2(x)}}dt= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2(x)}}dt$$
this is an [incomplete elliptical integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral)  $ \  \ F(t; k) := \int_0^t \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - k^2 \sin^2 u}}$
$$I=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} F\left( t ;\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)+C = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} F\left( \arctan(x) ;\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)+C$$